# C1FlexGrid : Check Merged Cell/Dynamic Merging

Tags: merge, cell, c1flexgrid

I have a Grid in which some rows are being merged on the basis of common identifier which is column one i have to do following things but i cant do it anyway to achieve it

1. I want to see if the first column is merged then second merged row should have a different color like in the preceding columns after 3rd column but its not being happening
2. I have to merge the preceding columns (5,6,7,8,10,14) on the basis of first column but like its merging the first column its not merging the preceding columns due to its common values like +4.50 is being merged for 2nd and 3rd and 4th record but it should only merged for its own record but due to the same value its merging all three records value

Kindly, help as i am badly stuck in this

i have [image]

Comment: Could you explain your second requirement. It is not clear from what you are asking

Comment: If you could edit your question to a more specific one, I'll post the answer here. If you need a complete sample code for your use case, then provide a small yet descriptive excerpt of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please understand that the style applied to a cell range is decided by the style in the topmost/leftmost  row/column. This is why in a single cell range we cannot have multiple styles.

**Note:** Please refer your comments and reply